# QGIS Server in an ipv6-only environment?

Tags: installation, qgis-server

Has anyone deployed any QGIS Server version in an ipv6-only environment? I need to ensure server-wide use of ipv6 only.

Any recommendations on how to do so on Linux and/or Windows servers, if you have?

Happy to expand but I'm  neophyte when it comes to working in server environments in GIS.

Comment: Are you talking about QGIS Server? Have you tried and did you run into any specific issues?

Comment: Sorry yes I meant server - thanks for giving me the benefit of the doubt there.  No we have yet to try, but we have some very rigid internal controls that inhibit our ability to playtest, and among them is ensuring any software set up for server-wide use is ipv6 only.